# File lock issues - Syncing through SCP client

Tags: file-locking, file-access, winscp

I'm trying to access files from an iPad. It supposes to plot some live data. However the data (file) that is being generated by the java program doesn't let the SCP client to sync the file to the server. It can access only on stopping the java program so that it can let go off the file that it writes. Is there way out for this? Like real time update of the server when the file is generated by the program?

Comment: Can you take another crack at the problem description? What platforms are running the different moving pieces? You mention an iPad but I'm confused where it comes in to play; `scp` doesn't necessarily make sense on an iPad...

Comment: Oh well Im syncing a file from windows machine to a live remote server using WinSCP. The iPad reads from the server. It just reads the file content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to run a command line version of scp as a system command from your java program (Sample code: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=8) each time you have closed the filehandle.

commandline scp: http://www.jfitz.com/tips/ssh_for_windows_doc_version2.html#CommandLineSSHSCP